# Create session using username and password.

Tags: php

I need to created login/registration system. User can submit his details  and its works fine , but I struggle to create session/log in user with username and password he submitted. When user put any detalis I got info: Notice: A session had already been started and results of that is anyone can get access to restricted sub page. Its seems like php code not retrieve recorded username and passwords. Thanks for any hint.

```
 <form form action=" <?php echo $self; ?>" method="POST">
     <div>
     <label for="user">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" />
     </div>
     <div>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];

    $file = fopen('filewriting.txt', 'r');
    $clean = array();

    while (!feof($file)) {
   $clean = fgets($file);
    }

    fclose($file);


    $clean['username'] = $user;
    $clean['password'] = $pass;
    if($user == $clean['username'] && $pass == $clean['password'] )
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $user;


    }
    } else {
    echo 'Invalid username or password!';
    }

} else {
    echo 'All fields are required!!!';
}
```

Comment: `<form form action=` => `<form action=`

Comment: And you can't start sessions after you've sent any output to the browser. Put `session_start()` before any HTML, whitespace etc. Also, I presume it's a typo, but you need to put your PHP code inside PHP tags... otherwise it'll just get output to the browser...

Comment: ...plus, you are using `<?php` `?>` tags, right? Show actual code used. As mentioned above, place `session_start();` above everything. I also hope that you've safely guarded against someone finding your `.txt` file. Using a DB would be better.

Comment: sure I m using it! but problem is, its not retrieve recorded details from filewriting.txt. Its create session when you put any username and password. Even when such username does not exist. I know its not safe, but its just college project.

Comment: Do this `<?php session_start(); ?>` nothing above that, then the rest of your code, while removing `session_start();` from above `$_SESSION['sess_user'] = $user;` - You can also try `if(!isset($_SESSION)){...}`

Comment: That big help, thank you! But its still allows login using any username and password. Its not get recorded usernames and passwords.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but you don't reset $_SESSION['sess_user'], so it may be just remembering the old value from previous tests, add unset($_SESSION['sess_user']) in the part where it says "Invalid username or password", see if that does anything. Also the guys above are right, create the session right at the very top of the page or it probably won't work whatever you try to do :P

Comment: No. Its seems its just not read array from txt file. When I tried print data stored in array its just show "Undefined variable: clean in"

Comment: This code is nonsense! read the [manual](https://php.net/docs.php) for each instruction

Comment: I hope you are hashing/salting etc. the passwords on the client and not have them stored as plain text.